# Using Jenkins Pipeline to query the Bluecat IPAM through the HTTP- request-Builder plugin

Tags: rest, jenkins, groovy

Apologies in advance for the length of the question but hopefully declaring script up front may assist future users in same boat as me.

I currently have a pipeline script in groovy which can successfully connect to my bluecat IP address manager and get me a Authorization token which in theory is all i need to be able to do subsequent calls to the Bluecat API and GET IP addresses or PUT new IP addresses into the IPAM DB.
thus far my script is:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic 

def jsonParse(def json) {
    new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(json)
}

def getPassword = { username ->
    def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials.class,
    jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance
)
def c = creds.findResult { it.username == username ? it : null }
if ( c ) {
    println "found credential ${c.id} for username ${c.username}"
    def systemCredentialsProvider =     jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList(
        'com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider'
        ).first()
    def password = systemCredentialsProvider.credentials.first().password
    return password
} else {
    println "could not find credential for ${username}"
}
}


// Gather Credentials
def BLUECAT_USER = 'BLUECAT_USER'
def BLUECAT_PASS = getPassword(BLUECAT_USER)

def BLUECAT_URL = 'http://ipam.main.org/Services/REST/v1/'
def LoginUser = 'login?username='
def LoginUserP = '&password='
def GetSysInfo = 'getSystemInfo' 

// ----- Get Session Token
def response = httpRequest httpMode: 'GET', url: BLUECAT_URL + LoginUser + BLUECAT_USER + LoginUserP + BLUECAT_PASS

if (response.status != 200) {
    error("Response recieved is not valid check your credentials.")
} else {
println "Valid response recieved."
}

//println BLUECAT_USER
//println BLUECAT_PASS
//println('Status: '+response.status)
println('Response: '+response.content)

def ResponseText = response.content
def Response = ResponseText.split(' ')
def Token = Response[3];
println "Your Session Token is : " + Token



def GetSYS = httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: 'GET', customHeaders: [name: 'BAMAuthToken', value: Token], url: BLUECAT_URL + GetSysInfo
def content = jsonParse(GetSYS.content)
println "SystemInfo: " + content["status_text"]
```

Credentials are stored in Jenkins' credential store and part of the script dives into the store to retrieve the password associated with the requested user account. (I make no apologies for ripping that part of the script straight out of Stack Overflow, it works so why mess with it?)

the issue i have is the final 3 lines of code thus far.
reading the documentation for the HTTP-Request-Builder plugin i cannot form the correct request to get the system information of the IPAM device.

the sequence of events should be as follows

using the bluecat credential set i can execute a get

```
def response = httpRequest httpMode: 'GET', url: 'http://ipam.main.org/Services/REST/v1/login?username=BLUECAT_USER&password=BLUECAT_PASS'
```

I get a response back with a BAMAuthToken, then i can call

```
def GetSYS = httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: 'GET', customHeaders: [name: 'BAMAuthToken', value: Token], url: 'http://ipam.main.org/Services/REST/v1/getSystemInfo'
```

where the Token is the authorization token obtained after a successful login.

this last line is what gives me an error and seems to point to me not forming my request correctly.
As is customary i have spent at least a week googling for what other people may have done.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/http-request-plugin

even here i don't see how to form the request and still pass the Auth token as part of that request.

I'm just starting with groovy and Jenkins, other people have done this API chatter using Java or powershell, i'm not a java Guy and powershell involves creating an DLL which i can do but then becomes very cludgy and incomplete in terms of feature set from what a few other people who went down that route have called out.

If anyone can help or provide pointers that would be appreciated
.

Answer (score 1):

Gone down the HTTPBuilder route with this ask. i am getting slightly better responses that are valid

thanks you for taking the time to look at this question